# How to add span tag in to Drupal webform element label?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am trying to style my webform checkboxes and radio buttons differently. For this reason I want to insert span element in to the label and use it instead of original checkboxes.

Found this module : https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_optionsmarkup , but non of the listed options appear in my webform field settings.

Does any body know good solution to accomplish this ?

```
 function bigdaddy_preprocess_webform_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'textfield' || $variables['element']['#type'] == 'textarea') {
    $variables['element']['#title_display'] = 'after';
  }
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'checkboxes') {
    foreach ($variables['element']['#options'] as $key => $one) {
      $variables['element']['#options'][$key] = "<span>jpnas</span>" . $one;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what you want by using the hook_form_alter() function. In my module's .inc file, I created a function like MY_MODULE_form_alter. I'll share my code...

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MY_FORM_ID') {
    foreach($form['ELEMENT_#NAME']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
      // $form['ELEMENT_#NAME'][$key]['#theme_wrappers'] = array();
      $form['ELEMENT_#NAME'][$key]['#prefix'] = '<span>jpnas</span>';
      $form['ELEMENT_#NAME'][$key]['#suffix'] = '<span>jpnas</span>';
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to place the span before the checkbox, use ['#prefix'].
Obviously replace MY_MODULE with the name of your module, MY_FORM_ID with your actual $form_id name, and ELEMENT_#NAME with the name of the form element you want to alter. Remember you can do a var_dump($form) if you need to see any of these values. I am doing pretty much the same thing it sounds like you would like to do, except I am not putting this into my label as I haven't found a way to attach directly to the label. The input element on the other hand is a different story. Furthermore, if you uncomment the first line in the loop, the wrapper  will be removed from around each checkbox, but it will take with it the label. You can then add the label yourself along with your own wrapper element using #prefix and #suffix accordingly.